# AngularJS - parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of photographs being generated like the following snippet.  Basically this would render a table like structure, with each photo being like a cell in this table.  The ID of each photo like for example 1D means that the photo is in the first row of the table and in the 4th/D column.

```
<ul>
   <li class="row">
      <ul>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-1A">1A</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-1B">1B</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-1C">1C</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-1D">1D</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-2A">2A</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-2B">2B</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-2C">2C</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-2D">2D</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-3A">3A</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-3B">3B</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-3C">3C</li>
            <li class="photo" id="photo-3D">3D</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have a JSON which includes whether the photo is available or not.  Basically the JSON string is something along these lines:

```
[{"row":1,"position":"A","available":true},{"row":1,"position":"B","available":false},{"row":1,"position":"C","available":false},{"row":1,"position":"D","available":false},{"row":2,"position":"A","available":true},{"row":2,"position":"B","available":false},{"row":2,"position":"C","available":false},{"row":2,"position":"D","available":false},{"row":3,"position":"A","available":true},{"row":3,"position":"B","available":false},{"row":3,"position":"C","available":false},{"row":3,"position":"D","available":false}]
```

Now basically what I need to do is to parse this JSON string and when any of these photos have "available:true" in the JSON string, I add a class photo-available in the HTML.  I am new to angular and I am not sure if there is an easy way to assign a class to the available photos.  Would be glad if someone can tell me what to use or how to do it.

Edit: Angular Code is this:

```
<ul class="table-rows">
    <li class="photo-row" ng:repeat="photo in photos" ng:class="'photo-' + photo.row + photo.position">
        <ul class="table-photos">
            <li class="photo photo-available" ng:class="selectedOrNot(photo)" ng:init="photo.selected = false" ng:click="photo.selected = !photo.selected">

         <div class="photo-number">{{photo.row + photo.position}}</div>                          
        </li>                                   
     </ul>                                
  </li>
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: angular.fromJson(json) returns an object which you can then work with

Comment: @c0d3junk13 thanks for your reply.  I managed to get the same by using JSON.parse(sessionStorage.seatBookings), however now I am completely stuck on how to go through each one of them and then when i find available=true, I assign the class photo-available to the corresponding <li>

Comment: whats stopping your from using "available" as the key and just reading the property value , it's an object after this , you can treat it as such !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update3**
The reason you are unable to restore previous selections is that you are overwriting the photo's `selected` property with `ng-init`:

```
ng:init="photo.selected = false"
ng-class="{'selected': photo.selected, 'available': photo.available}"
```

When you combine these two, the `'selected'` class will never be added because `photo.selected` has been hardcoded to `false`. You just need to remove `ng-init`, and the previous selection will trigger `ng-class` to add the correct class.

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/tVdhRilaFfcn55h6mogu

**Original answer**
If the list of photos is not the same array as the list of available photos, you can use a directive to add the class.

```
app.directive('availablePhoto', function($filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var id = attr.id

      var regex = /photo-(.)(.)/g;
      var match = regex.exec(id);

      var row = match[1]
      var position = match[2]

      var photo = $filter('filter')(scope.photos, {row:row, position:position}, false)

      console.log(photo);

      if (photo[0].available) {
        element.addClass('available');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then attach it to each list item like this:

```
<li class="photo" id="photo-1A" available-photo>1A</li>
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/WJCmLf2M39fcUnvOPyNA

**Update1**

Based on your update, I see that there is just one array populating the list, and it contains the `available` flag.  Therefore, you don't need a custom directive - `ngClass` will work.  Here it is integrated into your code sample:

```
<ul class="table-rows">
  <li class="photo-row" ng:repeat="photo in photos" ng:class="'photo-' + photo.row + photo.position">
    <ul class="table-photos">
      <li class="photo" ng-class="{'available': photo.available}" ng:init="photo.selected = false" ng:click="photo.selected = !photo.selected">
        <div class="photo-number">{{photo.row + photo.position}}
        </div>                          
      </li>                                   
    </ul>
  </li>
  <div class="clear"></div>  
</ul>
```

I have update the plunker to demonstrate this.
http://plnkr.co/WJCmLf2M39fcUnvOPyNA

**Update2**
Since you need `ngClass` to add multiple classes, use it like this:

```
ng-class="{'selected': photo.selected, 'available': photo.available}"
```

Demonstration of `selected` + `available`: http://plnkr.co/WJCmLf2M39fcUnvOPyNA

Comment: I have updated my question and included the code generating the <ul> structure.  Somehow when I am using your app.directive it is not working for some reason.  What I am not understanding is how from having "available-photo" in the <li> basically does the trick.  Also, I am not sure what your regex and code actually does.  Would be extremely glad if you can give me a quick explanation

Comment: Based on your update, my code isn't necessary because there are not two arrays. I will update in a few minutes.

Comment: just to have a better idea, I have uploaded my code here: goo.gl/MZK0Nb so you get a better idea of the actual scenario.  The question here is just for a related scenario

Comment: basically I still need the ng-class I have.  Is it possible to add to it, and have something like:
ng:class="selectedOrNot(photo); {'available': photo.available}"?

(you can see the thing working here: goo.gl/MZK0Nb . Basically the selectedOrNot puts the highlight state when the user clicks on the seat)

Comment: @user1809790, i wasn't able to open your goo.gl link, but i think i understand that you are trying to apply two classes conditionally using ngClass.  please see updated answer.

Comment: @j.witter this is something very close to what I need to obtain, but still it didnt work in my code :(  I have re-uploaded it and is available from http://goo.gl/MZK0Nb  .Basically what I need to do is the first time you enter and select the seats you get the highlighted/selected state.  But if you send the booking, and go back to the homepage for example and go back to the same film page, and the date and time of the show match, you should see the seats you have booked previously grayed-out, which is done by adding the class seat-booked

Comment: this is just a dummy application to try Angular and therefore once you  submit your "booking" I am actually saving in the local session (local storage) and when you try to access the same page again, I try to grab the JSON from your local session and then set the seats you had booked previously to booked so you wouldnt be able to re-book them

Comment: OK, so it really is more like my first answer.  You have two arrays.  One to populate the options, and one that holds previous selection.

Comment: @user1809790, figured it out.  see final updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plnkr with an example of how to solve your problem. You need to
make use of both the [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and the [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

http://plnkr.co/edit/hk68qp4yhEjcvOkzmIuL?p=preview

As you can see, I also added some filters for your photos, they will come handy if you need to just show the available ones (for some reason).

Here's the documentation for angular [$filter service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: I have added my AngularJS which is generating the <ul> structure.  FOr some reason when I am adding your code it is not working :(  Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: just to have a better idea, I have uploaded my code here: goo.gl/MZK0Nb so you get a better idea of the actual scenario. The question here is just for a related scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think this meets all your requirements:

```
$scope.photos = JSON.parse('[{"row":1,"position":"A","available":true},{"row":1,"position":"B","available":false},{"row":1,"position":"C","available":false},{"row":1,"position":"D","available":false},{"row":2,"position":"A","available":true},{"row":2,"position":"B","available":false},{"row":2,"position":"C","available":false},{"row":2,"position":"D","available":false},{"row":3,"position":"A","available":true},{"row":3,"position":"B","available":false},{"row":3,"position":"C","available":false},{"row":3,"position":"D","available":false}]');
```

and then you can just use `ng-repeat` to build the list:

```
<ul>
   <li class="row">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="photo in photos" class="photo" ng-class="{'photo-available': photo.available}" id="photo-{{photo.row}}{{photo.position}}">{{photo.row}}{{photo.position}}</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

So what we are doing is we are taking our photo array, and for every one (`ng-repeat="photo in photos"`) we are assigning that specific item to the variable `photo`.  Then, if `photo.available` is true, we assign the class photo-available (`ng-class="{'photo-available': photo.available}"`).

Then, we can simply interpolate the id and text based off the properties row and position (`{{photo.row}}{{photo.position}}`).  You could also have done that like this `{{photo.row + photo.position}}` but that could cause issues if they were both numbers.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hBkoyHVtIwF60MKDF84j?p=preview

Comment: So... you copied and pasted some code from my Plnkr? I see you have the same filter I added to my answer but you are not using it... Not cool man.

Comment: Yeah I wanted a Plnkr with angular set up, it's not like I stole your answer.

Comment: You took my answer and trimmed some *extra* filters I added in case he needed them.

Comment: No, you deleted your post, modified your plnkr, and then undeleted your post.  Yours didn't have ng-class at all when I did mine

Comment: In fact, plnkr lets you see revisions, so go ahead and click on either of the first two versions.  Kind of looks like you actually copied from mine

Comment: You took mine, edited and forked it while I was working on it. That's what the versions say. But as you say. Later.

Comment: @dave I am using an ng-repeat as above.  This gives you an idea how the <ul> structure is being generated.  Can you tell me where I need to put the ng-class="{'photo-available':photo.available}" as somehow it is not working for me :(

Comment: @GonchuB using a derivative of part of your work is perfectly acceptable in Stack Overflow, the missing bit is attribution.